# Как отличить, стоит приложение на iOS mobile device или iOS emulator

Tags: ios, эмулятор

Есть ли надежный способ идентифицировать (отличить), что приложение стоит на мобильном девайсе и на эмуляторе? Есть ли алгоритм, ID или что-то еще, что позволит однозначно понять, что юзается мобильное устройство, а не эмулятор на компе?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122149/iphone-simulator-how-to-detect-when-app-is-running-on-simulator-so-can-setup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458304/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-app-is-running-in-the-iphone-simulato